# HTTP Post JSON Object Using Tizen Native

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio, tizen-sdk

I'm trying to post data in JSON Format using HTTP Post in Tizen wearable native,
but there is no sample from their website. There is a code snippet for http request [HTTP Post Request](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads/http?langredirect=1)
but not specifying how to include a JSON Object. Can anyone let me know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: json-glib library works fine for Tizen native wearable 2.3.2 .. Any updates for 3.0? It dosen't work on 3.0

Answer (score 1):

In Tizen API References,
It's stated that:

Tizen Wearable 2.3.2 Supports: Json-Glib Version 0.10.4  ([Ref](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__OPENSRC__JSONGLIB__FRAMEWORK.html))

Tizen Wearable 3.0 Supports: Json-Glib Version 1.2.0  ([Ref](http://%20%20https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__OPENSRC__JSONGLIB__FRAMEWORK.html))

Migrate to 1.2.0 first.

This detailed Guide seems relevant:

[Native Application Dev Tip - Tutorial of JSON parser](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/native-application-dev-tip-tutorial-json-parser?langswitch=en)

Additional:
If still issue exists After Migrating to Json-Glib Version 1.2.0,  May try any other C Libraries for JSON.

http://www.json.org/

[CJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON) seems a good option also. Only copy the .c & .h files, You are good to go (As per the Guide stated).